# Getting the average of 5 students using multidimensional arrays C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I was wondering if somebody could please tell me what I did wrong in my code, It compiles but somewhere the information gets messed up. I'm new so I lack the knowledge I need to find the problem. Thanks!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

const int students = 4;
const int grades = 3;
float averages = 0;

float calculatingGrade(float studentGrade[students][grades])
{
    double averages[students];
    int i=0,j=0;

    for(i=0; i < students; i++){
        printf("Enter student#%d's grades:\n",i+1);
        for(j=0; j < grades; j++){
            scanf("%f",&studentGrade[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i < students; i++){
        for(j=0; j < grades; j++){
            averages[i] += (studentGrade[i][j]);
        }
    averages[i] = averages[i] / grades;
    printf("\nStudent#%d's average: %.2f ",i+1,averages[i]);
    averages[i] = 0;
    }
return;
}
void main()
{
    float studentGrade[students][grades];

    printf("Hello! This is a grade average calculator, enter up to 3 marks per student...\n\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");

    calculatingGrade(*studentGrade);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `calculatingGrade(*studentGrade)` -> `calculatingGrade(studentGrade)`. You should turn on the compiler warnings. Also `averages` is not an array.

Comment: @Osiris This didn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: Then you should tell us what exactly the issue is.

Comment: @Osiris After compiling and entering in the information the output is incorrect information.

Comment: What have you entered, what was the output? Also i see now that you shadowed `averages` but did not initialized it in the function. `double averages[students];` -> `double averages[students] = {0};`

Comment: @Osiris So entering 3 grades for example: 3.4, 7.5, 8.8. When you build the program and enter all of the sets of information its supposed to give you the average of each student. For some it displays the correct value and others a number like 1438204823843289080.000.

Comment: @AGNGazer Sorry, I didn't know what else to call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass an array to a function you have to pass it like this

```
calculatingGrade(studentGrade);
```

and must not dereference it first.

In your function `calculatingGrade` you are shadowing the variable `averages`, but you do not initialize it. If you turn up the warning levels of your compiler it should warn you about using an uninitialized variable. You also declared that function to return `float` but it should be `void` since it does not return anything.

This should work:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

const int students = 4;
const int grades = 3;

void calculatingGrade(float studentGrade[students][grades]) //no return value
{
    double averages[students];
    int i=0,j=0;

    for(i=0; i < students; i++){
        printf("Enter student#%d's grades:\n",i+1);
        for(j=0; j < grades; j++){
            scanf("%f",&studentGrade[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i < students; i++){
        averages[i] = 0; //initializing
        for(j=0; j < grades; j++){
            averages[i] += (studentGrade[i][j]);
        }
    averages[i] = averages[i] / grades;
    printf("\nStudent#%d's average: %.2f ",i+1,averages[i]);
    }
return;
}
int main() //main should return int
{
    float studentGrade[students][grades];

    printf("Hello! This is a grade average calculator, enter up to 3 marks per student...\n\n\n");
    system("PAUSE");
    system("CLS");

    calculatingGrade(studentGrade); //pass array correctly
return 0;
}
```

Comment: So was my problem that I was declaring averages = 0?  

Edit: Thanks this fixed it!

Comment: No. But you never used that variable therefore i removed it. Your problem was that you declared `double averages[students];` but did not initialize it. You added grades to it in the for loop but you never assigned 0 as initial value.

Answer (score 0):

Two main problems here.

First, you're calling `calculatingGrade` incorrectly:

```
calculatingGrade(*studentGrade);
```

By dereferencing the array, you're passing a parameter of type `float[3]` when the function expects `float[4][3]`.  Remove the dereference:

```
calculatingGrade(studentGrade);
```

Second, you're adding values to `averages[i]` but you never give an initial value.  This means the starting value is indeterminate, so it could be 0 or some other random value.  This is why you're seeing random results.

Set this to 0 before your inner loop:

```
for(i=0; i < students; i++){
    averages[i] = 0;
    for(j=0; j < grades; j++){
        averages[i] += (studentGrade[i][j]);
    }
    ...
```

In addition to these two points, `main` should always return `int`, and `calculatingGrade` should return `void` since you aren't returning any value.